# Fragment store and reuse : Multiple Child fragments with TabView

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

Hello I was stuck with multiple fragment store and reuse.

- My schenario

I have `3 Tabs`(without viewpager just fragment change) in `one Activity` and tabs having 2-4 Child fragments as like shown in below image.

so, When I open Activity.
1) **Tab1** load and Show **F1** fragment.
2) tap on **Tab2** and show **F1** fragment.
3) tap on button in F1 and move to Tab2's F2 fragment
4) again repeat tap on button at F2 and move to Tab2's F3 Fragment.
5) now I Tap on Tab3 and open F1 fragment.

this 5 working great with backstack **null**

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

but know,

6) when i tap Tab2 It will show F1 fragment always. becase i manage at activity like below snippet.

```
 switch (selected) {
        case 0:
            showFragment(TAB1.newInstance("", ""), TAG_HOME);
            break;
        case 1:
            showFragment(TAB2.newInstance("", ""), TAG_FAV);
            break;
        case 2:
            showFragment(TAB3.newInstance("", ""), TAG_ADD);
            break;
}
```

- **What I need.**

6) I need like, Suppose I tap on **Tab2** It show **F3** Fragment becase at `last time` in this tab2 I was `Opened F3` fragment.

So How To handle Store tab wise Fragment Backstrack.

And Yes Also need like below step(OnBackpress)

suppouse i am in tab 2 F1 ->F2 ->F3
after back press  F3 -> F2(backpress) -> F1(backpress)  -> close Activity

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `Stack of fragment in Hashmap` and retrieve when you change tab.

```
 HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks = new HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>();
 mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_A, new Stack<Fragment>());
 mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_B, new Stack<Fragment>());
 mStacks.put(AppConstants.TAB_C, new Stack<Fragment>());
```

While push fragment

```
 mStacks.get(tag).push(fragment);
```

While pop fragment

```
 mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).pop();
```

For working demo - [Github](https://github.com/pchauhan/FragmentTabWithDrawer)